# How do modify an existing SBT task conditionally

Tags: sbt

I want to modify the `publish` task and execute it conditionally (0.13.8). Here is what I tried (simplified):

```
publish := {
  Def.taskDyn {
    if (true) {
      Def.task {
        publish.value
      }
    } else {
      Def.task()
    }
  }.value
}
```

This fails with the following exception:

```
[error] (root/*:publish) sbt.Init$RuntimeUndefined: References to undefined settings at runtime.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```scala
publish := {
    if( true ) {
        publish
    } else Def.task {
        println("something else")
    }
}.value
```